# What purpose do relational databases serve?

Tags: python, sql, relational-database

Normally, when people advertise a tool to you, they *first tell, why you need it at all* and then discuss how to use it. That's not the case with first 5 books about databases and SQL I tried. It really feels like I'm talking to religious cultists :). They don't discuss: what the database is capable of, why it was designed the way it is designed, etc. They tell you that you should obey the 3rd normal form and Codd, the Prophet of it.

My question is: in what respects would my website, using e.g. PostreSQL backend as a data store, be superior to my website storing data in hash tables and using generic serialization mechanism built in my programming language of choice (like `pickle`/`shelve` in `python`).

I believe the answer is performance, but in this place SQL adepts are usually vague. I wonder, what operations cost so much less with databases? How does design help to achieve that? Really, when you're struggling with obeying some rules, you'd really like to know for what sake all that was?

Can you suggest a reading which first states goals then introduces notions of normal forms, relational algebra, etc. and then explains how those notions help solve the goals. 
Thanks, and sorry for a bit of ranting. To illustrate my problem, compare wiki article on [relational databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) to Stanislav Lem's [Sepulka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sepulka).

Comment: This is not a good type of question for this site. But you can look at the related questions on the right...

Comment: Instead of ranting, [try reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) - it's all there, I promise. Normal forms, Relational algebra, and ACID are all very important concepts with RDBMSes. Understand them and you'll understand *why* (and *when/where*) relational databases are good and appropriate .. and when/where/why they are not.

Comment: While the question is interesting and worthy of an answer, it's not really appropriate for SO.

Comment: @user2864740 Are Normal forms as important in RDBMS as Sepulka in civilization of Enteropia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sepulka ? 
One set of goals, RDBMSs are used for is ACID. Ok. Don't take offense, but the wiki articles on normal forms (just as most wiki articles) doesn't tell about purposes, it doesn't explain, how implementation satisfies purposes, it goes straight to implementation details from the beginning.

Comment: Normal forms are very important to relational algebra. Understanding RA is the key to understanding SQL and relational databases. One can "use" SQL but not understand RA .. its' one of those "Ah Hah!" moments. Otherwise you'll be left with high-level explanations of why/when to use SQL (or No SQL or New SQL) that someone else writes up. Remember that all databases ultimately serve one goal: to *collect and organize information*.

Comment: I would think that *any* cursory SQL book would explain the "goals" of a RDBMs system in the first chapters or preface ..

Answer (score 7):

I think there are two questions here:

1. *Why the relational model?*
2. *Why apply normalization principles when designing a relational database?*

A1. In answer to the first question, the relational model is an extremely flexible and powerful abstraction of data. It supports data integrity rules, data manipulation logic and ad hoc querying in a way that allows users to derive meaningful results from data without writing lots of code and without being burdened by underlying technical implementation details. These reasons, among others, make the relational model uniquely well-suited to a very wide range of use cases.

SQL is strictly speaking a *non-relational* model of data, only partly based on relational principles. However, SQL is closer to the relational model than many of the alternatives. Many of the basic relational ideas still apply in the SQL world and SQL systems are therefore often grouped under the heading of relational- and relational-derivative systems.

A2. Relational database normalization theory and the dependency theory on which it is based form a set of principles used to create and analyse database designs. The normalization principles help ensure that your database design accurately models the business rules you intend it to. Applying the principles will help you avoid certain kinds of data integrity problem that might otherwise arise.

Recommended reading: *Database Systems: The Complete Book* by Garcia-Molina, Ullman, Widom

Answer (score 1):

This seems to me like a question of SQL vs NoSQL - in your case a HashTable.

The big advantage of an RDBMS over a simple blob storage lies in the name. Relational Databases are good at storing Relations. While a BLOB storage might be all you need for some applications, most of the time, your objects will have relations.

You can have for instance users in groups and groups have permissions, it's easy to model this in the 3. Normal Form and afterwards retrieve the data, as well as modify the permissions. It would be more complicated to model something like this if you would have every user as an object with all its groups and permissions. What if you change the permissions of a group, than you need to check all users which are in the group and edit it there.

In terms of speed, it is obvious that a blob storage will retrieve the objects much faster, but using SQL you can perform a lot of operations directly on the database. You can modify your data to a certain point before reading them. This reduces the logic in your application and makes the whole data handling faster, since it's performed directly at the source.

This is what SQL gives you, however it isn't alway necessary and sometimes you are by far enough with a hash table. You need to choose based on your requirements which tool you want to use.

This seems to me like a good article if you want to have some more details in the differences between RDBMS and other storage systems: [RDBMS vs. NoSQL: How do you pick?](http://www.zdnet.com/rdbms-vs-nosql-how-do-you-pick-7000020803/).

More details materials about why to use RDBMS and what the features are depend to the server you want to use. Each server has a different feature richness and other trade-offs, so I would suggest you to just ask some *WHY*-questions on google or look at some pages with feature summaries of different RDBMS.